# Http request header 'connection' is set to 'close' and not 'keep-alive'

Tags: javascript, http, browser, load-balancing, oneops

I'm facing a very strange issue with my app hosted in prod oneops. When I am hitting the prod url deployed in oneops, http request header 'connection' is set to 'close' and hence connection is getting closed automatically.

Whereas when I hit the prod url with IP address, its request header 'connection' is set to 'keep-alive' and app is working.

I have a feeling its due to some configuration setting in oneops prod.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Have you got any answers for this?

Comment: This was happening because of some misconfiguration with load balancer. Check your LB configuration. Hope it helps

Comment: In my case it was SSL configuration issue. My server was on HTTPS and I was send data over HTTP. In that I had to enable SSL in angular. Starting server with ssl true worked for me `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json --ssl true`